# How does a strongly typed DataContext work?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

This is an in-depth continuation of [my question from earlier this morning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178090/is-this-a-spurious-warning-when-using-linq-to-sql), which I'm still stumped about. I'm using a strongly typed DataContext for my application and although it emits a warning, it magically works. How does it do this?

Here's the code one would typically use to connect to a database using LINQ-to-SQL.

```
class MyDatabase : DataContext {
  public Table<Widget> Widgets;
  public Table<Car> Cars;

  public MyDatabase (string connection) : base(connection) { } 
}
```

Even though it emits a warning, it works out of the box. One can begin reading from it using:

```
using (var db = new MyDatabase(connectionString)) {
  foreach (var w in db.Widgets)
    Console.WriteLine(w);
}
```

`Widgets` seems to be a field of the `MyDatabase` class. And in my code, I'm not assigning it to anything. But elsewhere, I'm reading from it and it has values. Why?

In other examples of LINQ-to-SQL, including code generated by Visual Studio 2008's DBML layout tool, the data context class may look like this:

```
public partial class MyDatabase : DataContext {
  public Table<Widget> Widgets {
    get {
      return GetTable<Widget>();
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the inclusion of `partial` and `GetTable`. Is the `partial` necessary?

I'm assuming my first example works by ultimately calling `GetTable`, but then where is this code coming from? How are the fields of my data context class being populated with data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are not properties, the only logical conclusion is that the base constructor has assigned them. Unexpected, perhaps, but not impossible.

The `partial` allows you to combine multiple code files into a single class; you only need it if you *have* separated your code file (usually for designers).

Some digging in reflector shows that the ctor calls into `private void InitTables(object schema)`, which does **exactly** this (reflecting over the fields, assigning them via `GetTable(Type)`).

Comment: Muy bueno! So, to answer my question from this morning, is it spurious? In as much as the compiler can't sense the reflection in the constructor, right?

Comment: @Mark - right. The warnings are incorrect: the compiler cannot detect reflection.